# AWS Cloud Watch: Can we use stats twice in a cloud watch query?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am working on a dashboard query where I want to have a count of all the transactions that took more than a certain amount to complete.

My query is something like:

```
fields message
| filter kubernetes.namespace_name = 'feature-7355' 
| filter message like "INFO"
| filter message like "Metric" 
| parse '[*] * [*] * - *' as logLevel, timeStp, threadName, classInfo, logMessage
| parse logMessage 'Header: [*]. Metric: [*]. TimeSpent: [*]. correlationId: [*]' as headers, metric, timeSpent, correlationId
| filter ispresent(correlationId)
| stats sum(timeSpent) as TotalTimeSpentByTransaction by correlationId
| filter TotalTimeSpentByTransaction > 2000
| stats count(timeCorrelationId) as correlationIdCount
```

When I try to execute this I am getting an error:

```
mismatched input 'stats' expecting {K_PARSE, K_SEARCH, K_FIELDS, K_DISPLAY, K_FILTER, K_SORT, K_ORDER, K_HEAD, K_LIMIT, K_TAIL}
```

Is there a way to work this out, Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: did you get an answer for this ? I am stuck with the same

Comment: Is it because its still an aggregated stream and not table? May be they don't expose difference between table and stream in cloudwatch.

Comment: Have you thought about about putting the ouptut of the first stats into another log group in cloudwatch?

Comment: No, not yet, also I am very new with AWS so still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Hey guys, some news related to this? I really would like to map some values by 60m... If someone got answer here, let us know